# Raspberry Pi: How can I import libraries inside the cv environment?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I've been following an opencv tutorial from [Sir Adrian Rosebrock](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/01/home-surveillance-and-motion-detection-with-the-raspberry-pi-python-and-opencv/#comment-452784) for a home surveillance system. This is working. I also have an analog sensor that is using an analog to digital converter which is ADS1115. This is also working.
the problem is once I insert the ADS library inside the surveillance code I get an error.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ss_security.py", line 17, in <module>
    import Adafruit_ADS1x15
ImportError: No module named Adafruit_ADS1x15
```

This is the code:

```
# import the necessary packages
from pyimagesearch.tempimage import TempImage
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import warnings
import dropbox
import json
import datetime
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import math

# Import the ADS1x15 module.
import Adafruit_ADS1x15

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-c", "--conf", required=True,
    help="path to the JSON configuration file")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--picamera", type=int, default=-1,
    help="whether or not the Raspberry Pi camera should be used")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# filter warnings, load the configuration and initialize the Dropbox
# client
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
conf = json.load(open(args["conf"]))
client = None

# check to see if the Dropbox should be used
if conf["use_dropbox"]:
    # connect to dropbox and start the session authorization process
    client = dropbox.Dropbox(conf["dropbox_access_token"])
    print("[SUCCESS] dropbox account linked")

# initialize the video stream and allow the cammera sensor to warmup
vs = VideoStream(usePiCamera=args["picamera"] > 0).start()
vs.resolution = tuple(conf["resolution"])
vs.framerate = conf["fps"]
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(vs, size=tuple(conf["resolution"]))

# allow the camera to warmup, then initialize the average frame, last
# uploaded timestamp, and frame motion counter
print("[INFO] warming up...")
time.sleep(conf["camera_warmup_time"])
avg = None
lastUploaded = datetime.datetime.now()
motionCounter = 0

# loop over the frames from the video stream
while True:
    # grab the frame from the threaded video stream and resize it
    # to have a maximum width of 400 pixels
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
    text = "Unoccupied"

    # draw the timestamp on the frame
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
    ts = timestamp.strftime("%A %d %B %Y %I:%M:%S%p")
    cv2.putText(frame, ts, (10, frame.shape[0] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        0.35, (0, 0, 255), 1)

    # convert it to grayscale, and blur it
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21, 21), 0)

    # if the average frame is None, initialize it
    if avg is None:
        print("[INFO] starting background model...")
        avg = gray.copy().astype("float")
        rawCapture.truncate(0)
        continue

    # accumulate the weighted average between the current frame and
    # previous frames, then compute the difference between the current
    # frame and running average
    cv2.accumulateWeighted(gray, avg, 0.5)
    frameDelta = cv2.absdiff(gray, cv2.convertScaleAbs(avg))

    # threshold the delta image, dilate the thresholded image to fill
    # in holes, then find contours on thresholded image
    thresh = cv2.threshold(frameDelta, conf["delta_thresh"], 255,
        cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]

    # loop over the contours
    for c in cnts:
        # if the contour is too small, ignore it
        if cv2.contourArea(c) < conf["min_area"]:
            continue

        # compute the bounding box for the contour, draw it on the frame,
        # and update the text
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        text = "Occupied"


    # draw the text and timestamp on the frame
    ts = timestamp.strftime("%A %d %B %Y %I:%M:%S%p")
    cv2.putText(frame, "Room Status: {}".format(text), (10, 20),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.putText(frame, ts, (10, frame.shape[0] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        0.35, (0, 0, 255), 1)

    # display temp
    cv2.putText(frame, "Temp: 30 C".format(text), (250, 20),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)


    # check to see if the room is occupied
    if text == "Occupied":
        # check to see if enough time has passed between uploads
        if (timestamp - lastUploaded).seconds >= conf["min_upload_seconds"]:
            # increment the motion counter
            motionCounter += 1

            # check to see if the number of frames with consistent motion is
            # high enough
            if motionCounter >= conf["min_motion_frames"]:
                # check to see if dropbox sohuld be used
                if conf["use_dropbox"]:
                    # write the image to temporary file
                    t = TempImage()
                    cv2.imwrite(t.path, frame)

                    # upload the image to Dropbox and cleanup the tempory image
                    print("[UPLOAD] {}".format(ts))
                    path = "/{base_path}/{timestamp}.jpg".format(
                        base_path=conf["dropbox_base_path"], timestamp=ts)
                    client.files_upload(open(t.path, "rb").read(), path)
                    t.cleanup()

                # update the last uploaded timestamp and reset the motion
                # counter
                lastUploaded = timestamp
                motionCounter = 0

    # otherwise, the room is not occupied
    else:
        motionCounter = 0

    # check to see if the frames should be displayed to screen
    if conf["show_video"]:
        # display the security feed
        cv2.imshow("Security Feed", frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

        # if the `q` key is pressed, break from the lop
        if key == ord("q"):
            break

    # clear the stream in preparation for the next frame
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

# do a bit of cleanup
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

I have just inserted the library. I w\haven't done any computations/readings. As you can see I placed a default temp value.

The library is located inside pi/Adafruit_Python_ADS1x15

---

Steps taken:

1. Installed the ADS library inside the cv environment (Error: destination path already exist)
2. Tried from Adafruit_Python_ADS1x15 import Adafruit_ADS1x15 (Error: No module named Adafruit_Python_ADS1x15)

Comment: Can you confirm that the ADS library is in one of the paths liste in `sys.path`?

Comment: Could you tell me what path are you referring to? I looked it up at /sys folder and there is no ADS there

Comment: It is a variable set in python. put `import sys` followed by `print(sys.path)` in a script and see what it prints (a list of paths). Then check that one of the paths points to the location of Adafruit

Comment: This is the result: ['/home/pi', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_ADS1x15-1.0.2-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_GPIO-1.0.3-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_PureIO-0.2.1-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']

Comment: Where did you get the .egg files from?

Comment: Adafruit's website. git clone https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_ADS1x15.git